# ParseException: Unparseable date:

Tags: java, datetime, parseexception

I have timestamp string like "2015-07-13T10:44:58Z" whe I try convert this in date object it always generates the exception

`Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-07-13T10:44:58Z"`

Code which I am using for parsing is like that

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Date subscriptionDate = format.parse("2015-07-13T10:44:58Z");
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What if you remove the last `.SSS` segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterm `SSS` stands for `Millisecond` - which means that your input needs to have 3 decimal places after the second - [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Your input, however, has no millisecond information. You have to remove the `SSS` or add the digits manually (`.000`).

Answer (score 1):

Your input is inconsistent with your pattern: pattern has millisecond information (.SSS) while input does not (it ends with seconds followed by 'Z'). So you should either provide milliseconds in your input or remove .SSS from date pattern